# If function based on another condition

Tags: excel, vba

is it possible to create if inside if function?

```
if maincondition 1 then

if condition 1 then 
....
elseif condition 2 then
....

else maincondition 2 then

if condition 1 then 
....
elseif condition 2 then
....
```

if main condition 1 is true then check the condition inside if wrong then go to the other maincodition

Comment: Yes you can nest `If...Then`  Are you having a problem with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier if you provided an example or looked up "*how to do VBA If statements in a user-defined function*". You also might consider looking at operators such as `And` and `Or`.

Here's a starter one for you.

```
Function SampleFunction(inputNumber As Long) As String

    If inputNumber >= 100 Then
        If inputNumber <= 200 Then
            SampleFunction = "it's between 100 and 200"

        Else
            SampleFunction = "it's over 200"

        End If

    ElseIf inputNumber < 0 Then

        SampleFunction = "it's less than zero"

    Else
        SampleFunction = "it's between 0 and 99"

    End If    

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

It was already answered, but just want to add my 2 cents based on your sample. Yes, you can `create` if inside if function...

The trick is that you need to make sure your `inner if` is ending before your `outer if`.

```vb
If some outer condition then
    If some inner condition then
        'do some stuff
        If some inner inner condition then
            'do some more stuff
        End if
        'do some more stuff
    End if
    'do some more stuff
End if
```

Read more on [If...Then...Else statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-ifthenelse-statements).

In your example, it would work with very small changes:

```vb
if maincondition 1 then

    if condition 1 then do something
        ....
    elseif condition 2 then
        ....
    End If
else maincondition 2 then

    if condition 1 then 
        ....
    elseif condition 2 then
    ....
    end if
end if
```

Indenting is important, especially when nesting anything, in order to see where something starts and ends.